# Multisite - disallow list of blognames during subsite creation

Tags: multisite

I need to prevent users from using particular blognames URL during site creation subdirectory multisite.

More or less need to reserve multiple names for future use.

Since there is a function that looks for existing names I imagine its possible.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `Network Admin > Settings > Banned Names`. It is just one line so if you have very many, better type them up in notepad first.

**The help text under it says:**

> Users are not allowed to register these sites. Separate names by
>   spaces.

Just type in all the names you want to reserve for later.

Banned Names should be about fifth or sixth down on the main settings page. Just above "Limited Email Registrations".

Comment: thanks, I looked at that and thought it was usernames...gotta read more carefully... duh